# Trigger js code with click

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("a#hm").on('click', function(){

    $.ajax({
            url: 'getTroskovnik.php', // make this url point to the data file
            dataType: 'json',
            //data:{id_akt:ajdi},
            async: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success:function(json){
                console.log(json);
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);
  // Create and draw the visualization.
  visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('tpltroskovnik'));
  visualization.draw(data, {'allowHtml': true, 'width': '100%'});
            },
            error:function(json) {
                console.log(json);
            }
        });

});
});
```

doesn't work for me when I put it in my web page, but it works when I write them in the browser console. What could be the problem?

Comment: Maybe the element `a#hm` doesn't exist yet at the moment the code runs.

Comment: Well if he does not use any templates and the page is loaded statically and he uses jquery ready event, this should be not issue.

Comment: i not use templates, i use ready event ... what can be problem?

Comment: also this a#hm is an bootstrap button inside google visualisation datatable ... maybe this can be a problem, but modal run well

Comment: Looks like element doesn't exist when you bind event then, as Felix suggested it, so try delegating event: `$(document).on('click', "#hm", function(){...});`

Comment: now work, so write as a answer to check as right solution if you want, thanks very much

Comment: Make sure the jQuery is loaded before the script executes. Can you make a JSFiddle that we can see?

Comment: its a complex source so its very hard to make jsfiddle... but this code work well $(document).on('click', "#hm", function(){...});